# ON c# I'm use Restsharp read data json client.Execute(request); why show format XML how do show format JSON

Tags: c#, json, xml, restsharp

ON c# I'm use Restsharp read data json client.Execute(request), why show format XML how do show format JSON my code below:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://omnamashiva");
        var request = new RestRequest("/omnamashivaya.json", Method.GET);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
        Console.WriteLine(content.ToString());
```

and I'm very confused. Why client.Execute(request) show output format XML. inthis below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <0>
        <id>2</id>
        <subscriberid>2</subscriberid>
        <cdate>2012-09-28 16:49:06</cdate>
        <sdate>2012-09-28 16:49:06</sdate>
        <first_name>Al</first_name>
        <last_name></last_name>
        <email>test@verizon.net</email>
    </0>
    <1>
        <id>29</id>
        <subscriberid>29</subscriberid>
        <cdate>2012-10-02 15:08:29</cdate>
        <sdate>2012-10-02 15:08:29</sdate>
        <first_name>Mark</first_name>
        <last_name></last_name>
        <email>test2@verizon.net</email>
    </1>
    <result_code>1</result_code>
    <result_message>Success: Something is returned</result_message>
    <result_output>json</result_output>
</root>
```

I want to show format JSON.inthis below:

```
{
   "0":{
      "id":"2",
      "subscriberid":"2",
      "cdate":"2012-09-28 16:49:06",
      "sdate":"2012-09-28 16:49:06",
      "first_name":"Al",
      "last_name":"",
      "email":"test@verizon.net"
   },
   "1":{
      "id":"29",
      "subscriberid":"29",
      "cdate":"2012-10-02 15:08:29",
      "sdate":"2012-10-02 15:08:29",
      "first_name":"Mark",
      "last_name":"",
      "email":"test2@verizon.net"
   },
   "result_code":1,
   "result_message":"Success: Something is returned",
   "result_output":"json"
}
```

Do yo know? How to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request executes correctly but the **server** returns XML instead of JSON. It is not a client-side error.
Most probably, the reason is that the server doesn't know the format of expected response and XML is default.

It's up to your server's settings. Maybe, he *always* returns data in XML. Maybe, he checks your 'Accept' header or something else. Read this server's ('http://omnamashiva') documentation. Once, I worked with API where I had to set expected response type in request XML body. It's all about server's configuration. Contact their tech support if you don't have documentation.

You may try *telling* the server what you are expecting by specifying expected data just as:

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

However, it may not work.